# How to make a route take many parameters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm doing something similar to a file-exchange application and I got to the point of creating folders, I want to make it possible to create a folder in a folder and the route was something like cloudstorage.com/folder/New_Folder/New_Folder/New_Folder.
How to get this format in vue -router

I have a route that simply takes the name of a folder and returns its contents.

```
path: 'folder/:name',
                name: 'folder',
                component: () => import("./components/FolderComponent.vue"),
                beforeEnter: (to,from,next) => {
                        axios.get('/api/file/folder/' + to.params.name).then(r => {
                            store.commit('set_files', r.data.data[0].files);
                            next();
                        })

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I founded solution by adding '+' at path then it be like 'folder/:name+'
And parameters like New_Folder/New_Folder will be returned by array in $router.params
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRYHi.png)